# malformed MIME header: missing colon: "Friday, September "

Tags: go, email, header, filereader, reader

I hope you guys are doing great. I've got a quick question. Is there a way to get that "Friday, September..." into the subject or another customized header? I'm getting this error "malformed MIME header: missing colon: "Friday, September "" whenever I try to read the file.

I tried to create another header manually but maybe I'm not doing it properly. Maybe I can indent those lines. Any idea of how to indent those lines from a text file?
Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/mail"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    msg := `Date: Mon, 23 Jun 2015 11:40:36 -0400
From: Gopher <from@example.com>
To: Another Gopher <to@example.com>
Subject: Gophers at Gophercon
Friday, September 
 21st 
1 - 3pm 
room 32c2

Message body
`

    r := strings.NewReader(msg)
    m, err := mail.ReadMessage(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    header := m.Header
    fmt.Println("Date:", header.Get("Date"))
    fmt.Println("From:", header.Get("From"))
    fmt.Println("To:", header.Get("To"))
    fmt.Println("Subject:", header.Get("Subject"))

    body, err := io.ReadAll(m.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", body)

}
```

```
Output:
2009/11/10 23:00:00 malformed MIME header: missing colon: "Friday, September "

Program exited.
```

link to playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ZmvUoOGdFdh

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. A general guideline about questions on StackOverflow : paste *text*, not *images*. With your current screen capture: I cannot copy/paste your code. Also, can you please add a link to your playground code ?

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I'll update the post. Here's the link to my playground https://go.dev/play/p/ZmvUoOGdFdh

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies here (and the error correctly mentions the line `Friday, September` ) :

```
Subject: Gophers at Gophercon
Friday, September 
 21st 
1 - 3pm 
room 32c2
```

there is no blank line between the headers and the `Friday, September`  line, so the parser tries to read `Friday, September`  as a header line, and complains.

---

If your intention is to have the date block of text as part of your email body : add a newline before

If your intention is to include all of these lines as part of the email title  :

- you can either remove the line breaks:
  If that title comes from some other string in your code, you can for example use `str = strings.ReplaceAll(str, "\r\n", "")`, or do some funkier things with regexps
- or you can have a multiline value for a header if *the following lines begin with a space* (as in [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3))
  for example : https://go.dev/play/p/pJLwWIffpfr

I don't think the RFC allows a `Subject:` to actually include a newline.

Comment: I see. Thank you, again. Hmmm I think it's a multiline value, but the people who worked on the files messed it up. If I remove the "\n" then it would all fall under one header haha. I'll keep trying, thanks though.